# Spoof the phone number for a text from an iOS device

Tags: ios, spoofing

so I am working on a project that requires anonymous reporting via text message. Instead of the user showing their number when sending a text, they can choose to (paid option) send it with an anonymous number to the person they are trying to contact. Is there any way to accomplish this in Swift? If not, what sort of server can I set up to handle a simple send message delivery? Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup an [SMS gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) on a server to deliver the SMS message for you.  [Here's an example of one of these in Node.js.](https://www.textmagic.com/docs/api/node-js/)  Thus, when the user wants to send the anonymous text message, you will have to send a request to your server (look into RESTful APIs if you haven't already) and the server will then have to send the message.